# How would i be able to make a 2 dimensional array, where the indexes are of 2 different type of files in a directory?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get files from a directory into a 2 dimensional array, where .txt and .mp3 types are seperated like in the illustration at the bottom.

Here is the code:

```
    List<twoFiles> filesList = new();
    public void ListFiles(){
        string pathDir = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "folderPath");
        string[,] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(pathDir, ["*.txt", "*.mp3"]);

        foreach (string[,] filePath in filePaths)
        {
            filesList.Add(filePath);
        }
    }
    public class twoFiles{
        
    }
```

How would i get the files from the directory in the array like illustrated in picture bellow?

[image: Image of how the array can function]

Comment: What if there are more files of one kind than the other?

Comment: @RaymondChen the plan is that the sorted alphabetically such, that the name of one .txt files has a corresponding mp3 file with same name. The files would then be checked to see if the correspomding file exist, if not an error would be thrown.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes. They should share the same name, such that the file in [0,0] has the same name as the one in [0,1].

Comment: I think the simplest way is to build two lists (one for `.txt` files and another for `.mp3`) files. After you've created the two separate lists, you zip them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of it as a "2 dimensional array" problem. You need a list of class objects with 2 filename properties.

Just a sketch:

```
// shorthand for a class with 2 readonly properties. 
public record TwoFiles(string Mp3File, string TxtFile);
```

```
string[] mp3Files = Directory.GetFiles(pathDir,"*.mp3");

List<TwoFiles> combinedFiles = mp3Files
   .Select(f => new TwoFiles(f, Path.ChangeExtension(f, ".txt")) )
   .ToList();

// optional, check
foreach(var combinedFile in combinedFiles)
{ 
   if (! File.Exists(combinedFile.TxtFile))
   {
      throw new ApplicationException($"Not found: {combinedFile.TxtFile}");
   }
}
```

Comment: I got an error at ToList stating MyApp.TwoFailes doesn't contain a definition for it. Are you using some type of namespace that makes it possible to use it?

Comment: I had added the ), but still got the error.

Comment: How does the check work? Does it check if a mp3 file with some name doesn't have a corresponding txt file? If so where does it show the throw of the exception?